# Is it bad that my unique element references a unique element?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

In my database schema I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
    event_id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4() ,
    event_name character varying(1000) unique,
    event_date timestamp without time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE details (
    detail_id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
    description character varying(10000),
    event_name character varying(1000) references event(event_name),
    unique (event_name,description)
);
```

In the "event" table, 'event_name' is declared as "unique".

In the table "details", 'event_name' references event.event_name AND is also declared "unique".

1. Is this bad practice?
2. Will this create unintentional behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: ""...In the table "details", 'event_name' references event.event_name AND is also declared "unique"..." -- no, that's not true.

Comment: @TheImpaler Why is it not true? I thought "unique (event_name,description)" declares 'event_name' as unique?

Comment: For `(event_name,description)` can the combinations (1, 2), (1, 3) valid when both present? Because in that case the tuple will be unique, but `event_name` won't.

Comment: @TheImpaler Ah now I understand you. Yes, only the combination is unique. Each element does not have to be unique. Thank you Impaler!

Answer (score 0):

`details.event_name` is not unique.

There is nothing wrong with the foreign key, even though it is unusual not to reference the primary key. The only problem here is the length: do you really want to duplicate 1000 characters in two tables?

The real problem with your data model is the unique constraint that includes `description`. Descriptions can be very long, which may exceed the limit for b-tree entries. And what good is that constraint anyway?

Comment: Is "unique (event_name,description)" for 'event_name' redundant then?

Comment: It is definitely not redundant. But what is the purpose behind forbidding two rows with the same name and description? Different descriptions for the same name are ok?